# Why is `str.reverse == str` faster than `str[0] != str[-1]`?

Tags: ruby

I ran some benchmarks and was wondering why reversing a string and comparing it to itself seems to be faster than comparing individual characters.

Reversing a string is worst case O(n) and comparison O(n), resulting in O(n), unless comparing the same object, which should be O(1). But

```
str = "test"
str.reverse.object_id == str.object_id # => false
```

Is character comparison worst case O(1)? What am I missing?

Edit

I extracted and simplified for the question but here's the code I was running.

```
def reverse_compare(str)
  str.reverse == str
end

def iterate_compare(str)
  # can test with just str[0] != str[-1]
  (str.length/2).times do |i|
    return false if str[i] != str[-i-1]
  end  
end

require "benchmark"

n = 2000000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  str = "cabbbbbba" # best case single comparison
  x.report("reverse_compare") { n.times do reverse_compare(str)  ; a = "1"; end }  
  x.report("iterate_compare") { n.times do iterate_compare(str)  ; a = "1"; end }  
end

       user     system      total        real
reverse_compare  0.760000   0.000000   0.760000 (  0.769463)
iterate_compare  1.840000   0.010000   1.850000 (  1.855031)
```

Comment: That's clearly not true in general. I constructed a random string of size 1,000,000, and obtained: `puts Benchmark.measure { str.reverse } #=>
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.006243)` and `puts Benchmark.measure { str[0] == str[-1] } #=> 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)` (as expected).

Comment: When I try on my machine, `str[0]` != str[-1]` is the faster of the two.

Comment: Try the .at() method which is probably better optimized in C than using indexers.

Comment: @Sztupy gives some reasons why `reverse` can be expected to be faster, but wouldn't you expect optimized C code for `reverse` to be faster than a method written in Ruby that produces the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two factors in favour of the reverse method:

- Both [String#reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-reverse) and [String#==](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) are written in pure C instead of ruby. Their inner loop already uses the fact that the length of the string is known, so there are no unnecessarry boundary checks.
- [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) however needs to check the string boundaries at every call. Also the main loop is written in ruby thereby being a tad bit slower as well. Also it will always create a new (one character long) string object as well to return which needs to be handled, GCd, etc.

It looks like these two factors have a bigger performance gain than what you get by a better algorithm, but which is done in ruby.

Also note that in your test you are not testing a random string, but a specific one, which is really short as well. If you woud try a larger one, then it is possible that the ruby implementaion will be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

To proof some thoughts of @SztupY. If you change a bit your code, like this:

```
def reverse_compare(str)
  str.reverse == str
end

def iterate_compare(a, b)
  a != b
end

require "benchmark"

n = 2_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  str = "cabbbbbba" # best case single comparison
  a = str[0]; b = str[-1]
  x.report("reverse_compare") { n.times do reverse_compare(str)  ; end }  
  x.report("iterate_compare") { n.times do iterate_compare(a, b)  ; end }  
end
```

You will get a bit different result:

```
#>            user     system      total        real
#>    reverse_compare  0.359000   0.000000   0.359000 (  0.361493)
#>    iterate_compare  0.187000   0.000000   0.187000 (  0.201590)
```

So, you could guess now that it takes some time to create 2 string objects from String.